# Displaying results of many sql queries without writing PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if this question might sound stupid to you guys, but am total newbie to programming, apart from knowing SQL, the thing is i have been given a MYSQL database containing various information about kids diseases and a web interface  written in php to create reports from the database that can be accessed via  the interface. there are almost 25 different variables that need to be computed in the report, i  have written sql queries to compute all these values, but i don't know anything about PHP, if i have all these queries isn't there a way for me to  combine all these sql queries to be display results on a webpage and come up with this report without writing PHP code?

Thanks for your

again very sorry if this is too basic.

Comment: No, php is your "controller" if you will, you will have to fetch and display it using that.. Though this isnt that hard of a task. Here's an easy example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: you will need to use a programming language to display to the webpage. Its not that difficult though and there are plenty of places you can get tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

As mr_jp suggests, phpmysqladmin provides a simple front end for running queries, but also changing the data and modifying the schema. Although you can restrict named users to only have SELECT privilege, they'll still need to know SQL to run the queries.

It's not that hard to build a front end to take a set of parameters, substitute them into a SELECT statement and send the output to a formatted table. There are lots of datagrid tools (e.g. phplens, phpgrid, have a google for 'mysql datagrid' for more) which will handle the formatting of a MySQL resultset (or just download it as CSV - your browser should be able to transfer the data into your spreadsheet program automatically).

There are a couple of report generators for PHP - but the last time I looked at this in any depth, I wasn't overly impressed.

Answer (score 1):

Your web host would probably have [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) installed. Try getting access from the web host.

You can enter your queries there and export the results as html, csv, excel and others.

Comment: Guys, many thanks for the support so far, this report will be required every month and needs to be accessed via a web interface. isn't there a way to feed all 25 queries into maybe a system or  a reporting framework which can display my results nicely in web interface

Comment: @Adolf I don't know of any general solution. You may create one by yourself or hire someone to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could write Python. Or Ruby. Or something you know. ;-)
But you need something to output your queried data.

If you just want to check the results by yourself without having the needs to publish that directly, you might use some MySQL query browser or administrator like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) or the [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). Those tools allow you to query the database but display the returned data only as raw tables. If you need some styling or your own layout, you'll have to use an own application or edit the exported data manually (e.g. using a CSV export and re-open it using some spreadsheet application like Excel or Calc).

Answer (score 0):

The combination PHP + MySQL is a very popular one and it's highly recommended that you use them together.

The code that you will need to write in order to display that information using PHP is pretty straightforward and not very hard. If you do know some basic programming concepts, you can learn to do that in a matter of hours. PHP is well known for its extremely accessible learning curve. There are thousands of code samples online that you can look at to see how this is done.

Comment: SoboLAN  and all,  would you mind sharing sites where i can download code samples which are doing similar things?